# System Up Time using C# is not correct

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan

I have the following code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dtime = DateTime.MinValue.Add(UpTime);
            string result = dtime.ToString(@"dd:hh\:mm\:ss");
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }

        public TimeSpan UpTime
        {
            get
            {
                using (var uptime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time"))
                {
                    uptime.NextValue();       //Call this an extra time before reading its value
                    return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime.NextValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is my system up time is 4 days 3 hours 22mins.

But application shows 1 day more.  i.e 5 days ...

How can i make it so its correct?

Comment: Are you aware, you are formatting your `DateTime` like a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: As @SonerGönül says: just show the `TimeSpan`'s value directly. Adding it to `DateTime.MinValue` will just give a `DateTime` uptime after '0001-01-01 00:00:00`. That it appears one day off is an accident of your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DateTime.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx) value is `01/01/0001 00:00:00`. So adding this value 4 days 3 hours 22mins, result will be `05/01/0001 03:22:00`.

And since you formatting *that* value, it is *too* normal to get `05` as a day part.

Instead of that, you can *directly* format your `UpTime` property as a `TimeSpan`.

```
var f = new Form1();
textBox1.Text = f.UpTime.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture doesnt exist for me.

Comment: `The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Just add `System.Globalization` namespace and you will get it.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton whenever you encouter a class that you don't know, you should Google it.  Would have pointed you towards [the MSDN entry for the class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and you would have seen the namespace it belongs too.

Comment: I thought it was quicker to ask...? I already Googled it and failed.